# MySQL InnoDB Foreign Key Problems

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, errno

I have the following tables and I am trying to run them in MySQL but I keep getting an errno 150. Just not sure why, but MySQL cannot seem to create the foreign key constraint. I have already looked at the rules for setting FKs for InnoDB and everything seems ok. Could someone please lend me another set of eyes and expertise?

```
-- Table publication_type (parent table)
CREATE TABLE publication_type (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  publication_type varchar(55)  NOT NULL,
  tstamp timestamp  NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT publication_type_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

-- Table publication (child table)
CREATE TABLE publication (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  authors varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
  publication_title varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
  publication_type_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT publication_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT publication_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (publication_type_id)  REFERENCES publication_type(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The types do not match:

`publication_type.id` is of type `int UNSIGNED`

`publication.publication_type_id` is of type `int`

See also the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html, specifically:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. **The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same**. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo, but I edited the script (see above) and it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Then run `SHOW INNODB STATUS` and check what the actual error might be.